# OpenOffice - java - add header in a RTF file.

Tags: java, openoffice-writer

I have a java based desktop application. There are a bunch of RTF files that it needs to read and modify. We are using OpenOffice for this.

We are successfully reading the RTF files and doing some modifications in them as well. However, we are not being able to add a "header" to the RTF file (the header / footer of the default MS Word functionality).

Has anyone done this using OpenOffice. If so, could you please share code / direct me to some information.

Thanks a ton.